# Unable to proceed with Facebook Business account verification: Stuck at 'in review' stage - Need assistance

Tags: facebook, facebook-business-manager

I am facing issues with the verification process for my Facebook Business account.

I have submitted my verification request for a Facebook Business account twice. The first time, Facebook informed me that it would take 5 business days for the review process. However, after 2 months have passed, my account is still stuck in the 'in review' stage. Following some advice on Stack Overflow, I decided to create a new business account and submitted the verification request for the second time. This time, Facebook mentioned that it would take approximately 2 business days for the review. However, it has been over a week, and I haven't received any response yet. My account is still stuck in the 'in review' status.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Facebook Business account verification? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this matter. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Same problem here. I'm at 1 month.  I've found no way to contact a human. I was about to delete the entire account and start again but based on your experience even that may not help.

Comment: @DaveW It's interesting to hear that you were considering starting over with a new account, but it appears that might not be a guaranteed solution either. I'm curious to know if there have been any updates on your end. Has your account been verified since you left that comment?

Comment: Yes, I did delete the account and start again. There didn't seem to be any other choice.

And yes, the new account got approved fairly quickly. HOWEVER I had found a better set of documents to support the application by then which was almost certainly the main factor.

If FB allowed you to edit or update your application that would be a far more efficient use of everyones time but I guess they don't have the resources to do that ;)